# Cookies on mobile safari disappear after app relaunches

Tags: javascript, ios, cookies, safari, mobile-safari

I have the a user authentication web page that sets a cookie using javascript using the code below.  It works fine on the desktop version of Safari, but when using mobile Safari on iOS (I've tested on iOS6 and iOS7) the cookie only persists until the mobile Safari app is terminated.  I can use the web inspector in Safari's debug menu to see the cookie initially has been set with an expiration date of 5 years in the future, and my other web pages can read the cookie no problem,but if I restart my phone or quit mobile Safari and relaunch the same inspector shows no cookie present, and my web pages.  I don't seem to have trouble with cookies set by other sites.  Has anyone seen this before?  What could be causing this?

```
<head><title>Authenticate</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setCookie(c_name,value,expiredays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
    document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+
    ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString()+ "; path=/;"); 
    document.cookie="expiration"+ "=" +escape(exdate.toGMTString())+
    ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString()+ "; path=/;"); 
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var address=prompt("Please enter the code:","")
if (address!=null && address!="")
{
    setCookie('address',address,(365 * 5));
    window.history.go(-2)
} else {
    document.write("There was a problem setting the cookie.")
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: 2021 also meet same probleam